# Spinner onItemSelected keeping called over and over again

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Well im new in Android programming and i felt a bit lost with the spinner selector...
I found some questions relating the same but none of them fits my purpose:

```
objectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.objectSpinner);
objectSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long position2) {

    Object object = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Log.d("Spinner", "itemSelected: " + position + " - Object: " + object);

    menuLayout = new View(this);

    if (object instanceof Filter) {
        Filter mFilter = (Filter) object;
        setAdapterFilter(mFilter);

    }

}
```

And heres the method where i set all the data to the spinner (The data of the spinner its initially loaded in onCreate method but it can change depending of what item the user selects from the spinner so the onItemSelected its called over and over again...)

```
public void setAdapterFilter(Filter filter) {
    frameLayout.removeAllViews();
    if (filter != null) {
        menuLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter, null);
        TextView typeTxt = (TextView) menuLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.type_txt);
        typeTxt.setText(filter.getType());

        frameLayout.addView(menuLayout, 0);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Filter> filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Filter>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, filterArrayList);
    objectSpinner.setAdapter(filterAdapter);

}
```

The main question is: How to change the behaviour of the Spinner? I just need that the onItemSelected event just be fired when its clicked (touched) and not when the adapter is set and the data is loaded.

Comment: Where did you set your spinner adapter?

Comment: At the beginning of the onCreate method, i used setAdapterFilter method with a null as argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnItemSelected` is always called when the `adapter` is first set. AFAIK, there is no way to stop this from happening. What you can do is set a `boolean` flag in your `Activity` and set it to true in your listener after it runs through the first time and don't run the code inside when it is false.

Using [onFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) could allow you to listen for the `Spinner` to get focus and do or don't do something when it gets focus. But I still think simply using a flag would be the simplest

Comment: Is there another way to catch an event when the spinner is focused? or at least clicked instead selected?

Comment: Yes, I have edited. I don't think `Spinner` has `onClick()` for dropdown

Comment: Thank you so much you solved it... some guys told me the same as you, using the flag its the simplest way but i wanted to solve it in some other manners just to learn.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've thought the same way and tried to make things harder just to learn...never works out well ;) Keep at it and you will have plenty of chances to use the more difficult things